# How can I download file with HTTPBuilder (HttpClient)?

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I need to download and save file. I'm trying to use `HTTPBuilder` because it has simple API and ***supports cookies***. I have written following code:

```
//create new httpBuilder and set cookies
def httpBuilder = ...
def file = ...  
def inputStream = httpBuilder.get(uri: urlData.url, contentType: ContentType.BINARY)
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream)
```

1. How can I check that file is correctly downloaded (not only the part of the file)?
2. For large files exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` occurs on line `def inputStream = httpBuilder.get...` How can I solve it?
3. May be it's not best choise to download files by `HTTPBuilder`. What is the best way to download file ***with cookies support***?

Comment: I don't know much about httpbuilder, but it seems the stream is being loaded into memory, can you check that?

Comment: Yep, looks like httpBuilder loads stream in memory in any case - if you are using clousure api or simple api as above. I have solved it with `httpBuilder.client.execute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried HttpBuilder GET request with custom response-handling logic:

```
httpBuilder.get(uri: urlData.url, contentType: ContentType.BINARY) { 
   resp, inputStream ->
       FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream)
}
```

If HttpBuilder has problems which is strange then you can always use the tried and true [Apache HttpClient API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) which has full cookie support.

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(req);
// validate response code, etc.
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

You can add a localContext when executing the request to manage cookies.

Comment: Yes, I have solved this problem with `HttpClient`. Don't use `HttpBuilder` to download large files